# Selecting matching columns and actions on those lines

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a file where I wanted to select lines where column $3 is the same. Now I have grouped them but I want to do certain actions on those lines in case column $1 (and/or $2) satisfies a certain condition.

For example - if all the values in $1 and $2 (within the group of lines that have the same value in $3) are within 0.1 from each other, I want to take the average of columns $1 and $2 (for that group that has the same $3). If it is larger, I want to just print those lines without taking an average.

My input is something like:

```
1.3   22.5  ALFA 45 50 
1.4   22.6  ALFA 45 50
1.5   22.7  ALFA 45 50
1.6   22.8  ALFA 45 51
5.5   8.5   BETA 53 15
5.6   8.6   BETA 53 15
5.5   8.5   BETA 53 15
7.6   10.6  GAMA 75 13
7.7   10.7  GAMA 76 13
12    11.5  GAMA 75 13
4.5   4.5   DELTA 65 12 
4.6   5.7   DELTA 65 12
12.1    8   EPS  44 16
12.2    8   EPS  44 16
```

I want my output to be:

out1.txt:

```
5.53    8.53 BETA  53 15
12.15   8    EPS  44 16
```

out2.txt:

```
1.3   22.5  ALFA 45 50  
1.4   22.6  ALFA 45 50 
1.5   22.7  ALFA 45 50 
1.6   22.8  ALFA 45 50  
7.6   10.6  GAMA 75 13 
7.7   10.7  GAMA 76 13 
12    11.5  GAMA 75 13 
4.5   5.6   DELTA 65 12 
4.6   9     DELTA 65 12
```

Comment: sample input/output will help you to get more responses and to verify the scripts.  This seems a trivial exercise for `awk`

Comment: I might have been unclear in the question. I don't have a script to verify, I just don't know how to write one for choosing a line when I am not selecting a specific pattern but only certain matching.

Comment: people can verify their own scripts whether it matches your output or not. Writing a good specification is a non trivial exercise.  For example what if your $3 values fill a range `0.9 0.95 1 1.05 1.1 1.15 1.2` or clustered around two values? (bi-modal)  `0.9 1.1 0.95 2 2.01 1.91`

Comment: Now I understood what you meant, I edited the post.

Comment: @karakfa is it now trivial enough? :) I haven't managed to find a solution yet

Comment: yes better now.  please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk   '{k=$3;
         if(!(k in min1)) {max1[k]=min1[k]=$1; max2[k]=min2[k]=$2}
         sum1[k]+=$1; sum2[k]+=$2; count[k]++;
         if(max1[k]<$1) max1[k]=$1; if(min1[k]>$1) min1[k]=$1;
         if(max2[k]<$2) max2[k]=$2; if(min2[k]>$2) min2[k]=$2}    
    END {for(k in sum1) 
            if(max1[k]-min1[k]<=0.1 && max2[k]-min2[k]<=0.1)
               printf "%.2f\t%.2f\t%s\n",sum1[k]/count[k],sum2[k]/count[k],k}' file

12.15   8.00    EPS
5.53    8.53    BETA
```

a lot of code but almost trivial, the order is not preserved though.

Comment: Thanks! And if I would have more columns in my input file, how could I print them? Like in edited question input/output.

Using sth like `print {$4,$5}` prints the same values of columns 4 and 5 for each line instead of the corresponding line

Comment: the easiest is to make them part of the key.  change to `k=$3 FS $4 FS $5`.  At one point you have to up vote and accept answers.  Otherwise, people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Ok. And min1 and min2 are in this case awk functions for minimum and maximum or names of values?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, I've only now seen the option of accepting an answer.

Comment: min1/max1 are just variable names (here array), max/min are computed within the script.